# Map with hover area showing alt text in div - relative to hovered area

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hover, area

I'm trying to get a div to show with the alt text of the hovered area - positioned relative to the hovered area.

I can get the text to show, but not in the right place.

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#Map')) {
    $('#Map area').each(function() {
    var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
    $("#popup").html(altText);
            $('#popup').show();

        });

        $(this).mouseout(function() {
    var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
            $('#popup').hide();
        });

    });
}
});
```

Comment: are you using leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popup").draggable();
    if ($('#Map')) {
        $('#Map area').each(function () {
            var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
            $(this).mouseover(function (event) {

                $("#popup").html(altText);
                $("#popup").css({ 'top': event.clientY, 'left': event.clientX });
                $('#popup').show();

            });

            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
                $('#popup').hide();
            });

        });
    }
});
```

you need to make the div draggabele, then only it will change the position dynamicallly

Comment: Hmm, I don't want the div to be draggable, and I've tried using the css to position it relative to the hovered area, but it doesn't seem to make a difference?? http://jsfiddle.net/pSbYX/

Comment: @user2306046, i have updated the answer, it will work perfectly. If it works, please accept it as an answer..

Comment: Thanks, thats great. But see how when I add anything else to the page it moves the box further down? How do I adjust for this? (I added the h1) http://jsfiddle.net/pSbYX/2/